# Mailchimp - add checkbox to list fields

Tags: mailchimp

I started to use mailchimp and finds it very helpful.

However, I would like to add to my list a checkbox field, and cannot find it.
I neither find a way to give a default value (for example, I could think of a non-elegant way to use a radio button instead of a checkbox...).

Help please? Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

MailChimp handles their information very specifically:

**Fields** are for information about each subscriber that help you identify them (first name, last name, email, city, state, gender, etc). Fields do not allow for checkboxes.

Then you have **groups**, which are basically ways to organize your subscribers based on their interests. You create a group, give it a name, and enter your choices. Here is where you can use checkboxes, or you can use radio buttons or dropdowns. You would use groups to ask something like "What topics would you like to receive emails about?" or "What sports are you interested in?"

You can then create **segments** based on fields, groups, or both. Once you generate a segment, you can then send a mailing to that segment.

Answer (score 0):

For MailChimp, the "checkbox" choices are a way to create a GROUP with different options for that group .. for which there is no default value.

Radio Buttons creates a field and does provide for a default value if nothing is entered.

The use of checkbox vs radiobutton is not just a UI choice, it is a functionality choice.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Not really... can you please explain more? As I said, what I really need is a checkbox functionality, However I do not understand from your answer whether it is possible, and if it is - how.